# Full width in Sub-Menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, position, width

Needs to :
I'm having a problem trying to achieve a navigation design.
I need a full-screen Width for a Sub-Menu
I work on Wordpress, with a template (Innovio), and I'm a beginner in wordpress and JS. I really don't understand how to do. I tried to 1/ make a full width for ,2/  make a left:0 and full width, nothing change and my sub-menu take all his items more bigger than his container.

Problems :
When I hovered my btn-menu, my sub-menu is completly on the left and not in full screen.

Someone can help me please ?
Code HTML:

```
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-6318" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom " style="height: 61.5px;"><a href="https://bcm-lab.com/lab-1/modalites-pedagogiques/#Blended" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_text"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 26 9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 26 9;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path d="M26,4.7C26,4.6,26,4.4,26,4.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2l-3.5-3.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7L24.3,4
                    H0.5C0.2,4,0,4.2,0,4.5S0.2,5,0.5,5h23.8l-2.7,2.7c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1s0.3,0,0.4-0.1l3.5-3.5
                    C25.9,4.8,25.9,4.8,26,4.7z"></path>
                </svg>Blended</span></span></a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-6319" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom " style="height: 61.5px;"><a href="https://bcm-lab.com/lab-1/modalites-pedagogiques/#Inter-entreprises" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_text"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 26 9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 26 9;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path d="M26,4.7C26,4.6,26,4.4,26,4.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2l-3.5-3.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7L24.3,4
                    H0.5C0.2,4,0,4.2,0,4.5S0.2,5,0.5,5h23.8l-2.7,2.7c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1s0.3,0,0.4-0.1l3.5-3.5
                    C25.9,4.8,25.9,4.8,26,4.7z"></path>
                </svg>Inter-entreprises</span></span></a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-6320" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom " style="height: 61.5px;"><a href="https://bcm-lab.com/lab-1/modalites-pedagogiques/#Digital" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_text"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 26 9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 26 9;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path d="M26,4.7C26,4.6,26,4.4,26,4.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2l-3.5-3.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7L24.3,4
                    H0.5C0.2,4,0,4.2,0,4.5S0.2,5,0.5,5h23.8l-2.7,2.7c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1s0.3,0,0.4-0.1l3.5-3.5
                    C25.9,4.8,25.9,4.8,26,4.7z"></path>
                </svg>100% Digital</span></span></a></li>
       <li id="nav-menu-item-6321" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom " style="height: 61.5px;"><a href="https://bcm-lab.com/lab-1/modalites-pedagogiques/#Pr%C3%A9sentiel" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_text"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 26 9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 26 9;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path d="M26,4.7C26,4.6,26,4.4,26,4.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2l-3.5-3.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7L24.3,4
                    H0.5C0.2,4,0,4.2,0,4.5S0.2,5,0.5,5h23.8l-2.7,2.7c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1s0.3,0,0.4-0.1l3.5-3.5
                    C25.9,4.8,25.9,4.8,26,4.7z"></path>
                </svg>Présentiel</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Code JS:

```
function mkdfSetDropDownWideMenuPosition(){
        var menuItems = $(".mkdf-drop-down > ul > li.wide");

        
        if(menuItems.length) {
            menuItems.each( function(i) {
                var menuItem = $(this);
                var menuItemSubMenu = menuItem.find('.second');
                
                if(menuItemSubMenu.length && !menuItemSubMenu.hasClass('left_position') && !menuItemSubMenu.hasClass('right_position')) {
                    menuItemSubMenu.css('left', 0);
                    
                    var left_position = menuItemSubMenu.offset().left;
                    
                    if(mkdf.body.hasClass('mkdf-boxed')) {
                        //boxed layout case
                        var boxedWidth = $('.mkdf-boxed .mkdf-wrapper .mkdf-wrapper-inner').outerWidth();
                        menuItemSubMenu.css({'width': boxedWidth});

                    } else if(mkdf.body.hasClass('mkdf-wide-dropdown-menu-in-grid')) {
                        //wide dropdown in grid case
                        menuItemSubMenu.css({'width': mkdf.gridWidth()});

                    }
                    else {
                        //wide dropdown full width case
                        menuItemSubMenu.css({'width': mkdf.windowWidth});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```